# Elasticsearch Field with different types

Tags: elasticsearch, templates, indexing

I try to create an index template for my heterogeneous data. Is there a way to ingest Documents with a field that is sometimes a list of lists:

```
{
  "xx_response_body": [
    [
      123123,
      ...
    ],
    [
      12312344,
      ...
    ],
    
    ....
  ],
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Vary": "Cookie",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}
```

and sometimes an object:

```
{
  "xx_response_body": {
    "abc": "error",
    "def": "content",
    "hij": {}
  },
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}
``
```

Comment: Not possible, a field in an index can have only one type. If your field can be a string or array of string in some documents and a json object in other documents, you will need to choose one type and rename the field with the other type during the ingestion process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off by creating different fields for these types of fields or storing your data in separate indices, your future self will thank you.

There's also [`flattened`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html) data type that might work, but I've not used that in the past.

Another alternative approach would be storing this information as a string and using [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) to extract these fields if you wanted to, but that will always be slower than actually indexing them.